# Meaning of "way" in a context?

Tags: meaning-in-context

Hopefully you are fine!

> This apparent victory in the Newton Wars of the 1730s and 1740s allowed Voltaire's new philosophical identity to solidify. Especially crucial was **the way that** it allowed Voltaire's outlaw status, which he had never fully repudiated, to be rehabilitated in the public mind as a necessary and heroic defense of philosophical truth against the enemies of error and prejudice.

I am a bit confused about the usage of the word "way" in the aforementioned excerpt. To specify exactly what is irking me, I will frame my question in the following two points:

1: First of all, my understanding is that if "the way" is eliminated from the sentence, it's meaning will remain intact. Is it correct?

2: Secondly, if "way" is really giving the meaning of "method" here, then shouldn't it be "Especially crucial was **the way which** allowed" ?

Comment: 1: No. 2: Why do you think *which* would be correct and *that* not? Can you expand?

Comment: In fact, "Especially crucial was the way which allowed" shifts the reference of *way* -- the meaning is lost.

Comment: @Kris because "way" is a noun. He expects either "the way in which it" or "the way which allowed". Yes, "the way that it allowed" is common usage, but that is not the question. He wants to know the specific grammar of "the way that".

Comment: @Mushrraf Baig Ashraf, interesting. "Way" is the subject! What about "The way that raccoons wash their food is interesting." I don't have an answer, though.

Comment: And yes, "the way" is actually unnecessary. It was more the *fact* that it allowed this, not the particular way it did so.

Comment: @Kris Thank you very much for your reply. 

The issue is not related to the choice between "which" or "that", as ChuckkHubbard alluded .  I should rewrite my second point in this way:

"Especially crucial was the way which/it allowed" The  point is that "it" seems to be - according to my understanding - redundant

Comment: @ChuckkHubbard Thanks for your response.

1: In the sentence which you mentioned "The way that raccoons wash their food is interesting.", that seems  redundant as well. As the meaning is smooth without it. Here is a usage of "the way" in thefreedictionary.com:

/////////
In the manner that: The way he talks, you'd think he ran the company. 
/////////

2: Yes. It makes sense to me when we take it in the meaning of "fact". The only problem was that I didn't find any such usage in online resources.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. No. The context is derived from the complete integrated sentence. *"Especially crucial was the way that it allowed Voltaire's outlaw status to be rehabilitated in the public mind as a necessary and heroic defense of philosophical truth against the enemies of error and prejudice."*
2. *'the way'* connects to; the process engaged in - route taken, path followed, which ended up helping to change Voltaire's public identity as an outlaw. Used as an alternative; "Especially crucial was the process engaged in which altered Voltaire's outlaw status,"

Comment: Thanks for your reply, Norman Edward.  And, the alternative which you mentioned really helped me understand the point. And looking at this alternative, I would like to confirm one aspect which may be implied in your reply.

Does it mean that in "the way that it allowed" either it or that is redundant. I mean that if we just say "especially crucial was the way that allowed", it should give same meaning, just like in your alternative you said: "Especially crucial was the process engaged in which altered" and didn't mention "it" after "which".

Comment: @Mushrraf Baig Ashraf In your example, though, the "it" clearly refers to something mentioned in a previous sentence. Do you have the rest of the text to share?

Comment: @ChuckkHubbard

The text is available here: 
https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/voltaire/

It is just in the beginning of the text under the title:
"1.5 From French Newtonian to Enlightenment Philosophe (1745–1755)"

I hope that you will have a clear picture of it with its pre-context and post-context.

Comment: This apparent victory in the Newton Wars of the 1730s and 1740s allowed Voltaire's new philosophical identity to solidify. Especially crucial was the way that it allowed Voltaire's outlaw status, which he had never fully repudiated, to be rehabilitated in the public mind as a necessary and heroic defense of philosophical truth against the enemies of error and prejudice." So "it" means the apparent victory from the previous sentence.

Comment: "that" is not a pronoun here, as in "The way that happened," but a conjunction, as in, "the one that you love." I'd have to check a book to know if that's considered proper, then if I have time, I'll post an actual answer.

Comment: @ChuckkHubbard Thanks for you time. Your description makes sense. I just want to  confirm that you are taking "way" in this context to mean "fact" or "matter". i.e., "especially crucial was the fact/matter that it(the apparent victory) allowed ..." And, if this is true, then I think that "that" can be taken as description of "way".

Comment: @Mushrraf Baig Ashraf  Chuck, you and I are almost agreed on every item in the sentence except 'way' or 'the way'. Let me create another sentence with the same specific references. " To get to grandmas house was a two hour drive.  Mom always took the route that went by an ice cream stand. She chose **the way that** had us look forward to our long drive there."

Comment: @NormanEdward The sentence which you created makes sense and here "the way" means "the way" and we don't need to take it in the meaning of "fact". And, if we remove "it" from the sentence under discussion and say: "Especially crucial was the way that [it] allowed Voltaire's outlaw status to be rehabilitated in the public mind as a necessary and heroic defense of philosophical truth against the enemies of error and prejudice." then everything is clear and there is no doubt. But, the ambiguity arises when we put "it" after "that".

Comment: @Mushrraf Baig Ashraf  - I agree.  '...that allowed...'  makes a clearer connection than '...that allowed it...'.

Comment: @NormanEdward Thank you for your precious time! And, I am hopeful that I, being a student, would get your support in the future as well!